# Not able to create text[][] column in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to store 2D Array in postgres.
SQL command

```
CREATE TABLE public.abc (
id serial, 
data text[][]
)
```

It is not creating column as text[][]. It is creating column as text[]. When I'm trying to store 2D array then it is giving error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Native Method)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.appendArray(PgConnection.java:1190)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createArrayOf(PgConnection.java:1317)
```

Java code to store 2D array

```
    final String[][] element = new String[2][]; 
elements[0] = new String[] {"meeting_m","lunch_m"}; 
elements[1] = new String[] {"training_m","presentation_m"}; 
        ps.setArray(4,jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createArrayOf("text", element));
```

Comment: The `create table` will not result in that error. Show us your Java code that inserts the data. Also: Postgres does not have multidimensional arrays: [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION): "*The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of dimensions either (...) So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in CREATE TABLE is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.*"

Comment: final String[][] elements = new String[2][];
     elements[0] = new String[] {"meeting_m","lunch_m"};
        elements[1] = new String[] {"training_m","presentation_m"}; 

ps.setArray(4, jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createArrayOf("text", elements));

Comment: Do **not** post code in comments. [edit] your question